# jhipster-registry: spring cloud config conf with ssh throws is not a valid private key

Tags: jhipster, spring-cloud-config, jhipster-registry

Im trying to start jhipster-registry with **prod**-profile (from my local machine, to test prod configuration among other things) with the following docker-compose file

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  jhipster-registry:
    image: jhipster/jhipster-registry:v6.8.0
    volumes:
      - ./central-server-config:/central-config
    # When run with the "dev" Spring profile, the JHipster Registry will
    # read the config from the local filesystem (central-server-config directory)
    # When run with the "prod" Spring profile, it will read the configuration from a Git repository
    # See https://www.jhipster.tech/jhipster-registry/#spring-cloud-config
    environment:
      - _JAVA_OPTIONS=-Xmx512m -Xms256m
      - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=prod,api-docs
      - SPRING_SECURITY_USER_PASSWORD=changeme
      - JHIPSTER_REGISTRY_PASSWORD=changeme
      - SPRING_CLOUD_CONFIG_SERVER_COMPOSITE_0_TYPE=git
      - SPRING_CLOUD_CONFIG_SERVER_COMPOSITE_0_URI=git@github.com:<user>/<git-repo-config>.git
      - SPRING_CLOUD_CONFIG_SERVER_COMPOSITE_0_IGNORE_LOCAL_SSH_SETTINGS=true
      - SPRING_CLOUD_CONFIG_SERVER_COMPOSITE_0_HOST_KEY=github.com
      - SPRING_CLOUD_CONFIG_SERVER_COMPOSITE_0_HOST_KEY_ALGORITHM=ssh-rsa
      - SPRING_CLOUD_CONFIG_SERVER_COMPOSITE_0_PRIVATE_KEY=|
                                                        -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
                                                        DDVHEEYGbSQ6hIGSh0I7BQun0aLRZojfE3gqHQIDAQABAoIBAQCZmGrk8BK6tXCd
                                                        DDVHEEYGbSQ6hIGSh0I7BQun0aLRZojfE3gqHQIDAQABAoIBAQCZmGrk8BK6tXCd
                                                        DDVHEEYGbSQ6hIGSh0I7BQun0aLRZojfE3gqHQIDAQABAoIBAQCZmGrk8BK6tXCd
                                                        DDVHEEYGbSQ6hIGSh0I7BQun0aLRZojfE3gqHQIDAQABAoIBAQCZmGrk8BK6tXCd
                                                        DDVHEEYGbSQ6hIGSh0I7BQun0aLRZojfE3gqHQIDAQABAoIBAQCZmGrk8BK6tXCd
                                                        DDVHEEYGbSQ6hIGSh0I7BQun0aLRZojfE3gqHQIDAQABAoIBAQCZmGrk8BK6tXCd
                                                        DDVHEEYGbSQ6hIGSh0I7BQun0aLRZojfE3gqHQIDAQABAoIBAQCZmGrk8BK6tXCd
                                                        DDVHEEYGbSQ6hIGSh0I7BQun0aLRZojfE3gqHQIDAQABAoIBAQCZmGrk8BK6tXCd
                                                        DDVHEEYGbSQ6hIGSh0I7BQun0aLRZojfE3gqHQIDAQABAoIBAQCZmGrk8BK6tXCd
                                                        DDVHEEYGbSQ6hIGSh0I7BQun0aLRZojfE3gqHQIDAQABAoIBAQCZmGrk8BK6tXCd
                                                        -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
    # - SPRING_CLOUD_CONFIG_SERVER_COMPOSITE_0_SEARCH_PATHS=central-config
    # If you want to expose these ports outside your dev PC,
    # remove the "127.0.0.1:" prefix
    ports:
      - 127.0.0.1:8761:8761
```

According to the [docs](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/reference/html/#_authentication), it only support ssh-rsa format so I create a new ssh key with rsa and PEM format (`ssh-keygen -m PEM -t rsa -b 4096 -C "<user@domain.com>"`) and no password and upload ([the public key)](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account) to my git account.
I tested that I can push to my **< config-git-repo >.git** using this private rsa key. I have checked that the generated keys are in a PEM format (starts with **-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----**), according to the [docs](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/reference/html/#_authentication).

But the registry fails to start (docker-compose -f registry.yml up) with exception

```
jhipster-registry_1  | Caused by: org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.validation.BindValidationException: Binding validation errors on spring.cloud.config.server.git
```

jhipster-registry_1  |    - Error in object 'spring.cloud.config.server.git': codes [PrivateKeyIsValid.spring.cloud.config.server.git,PrivateKeyIsValid]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [spring.cloud.config.server.git.,]; arguments []; default message []]; default message [Property 'spring.cloud.config.server.git.privateKey' is not a valid private key]

According to the docs:

```
Warning: When working with SSH keys, the expected ssh private-key must begin with -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----. If the key starts with -----BEGIN OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY----- then the RSA key will not load when spring-cloud-config server is started. The error looks like:
```

- Error in object 'spring.cloud.config.server.git': codes [PrivateKeyIsValid.spring.cloud.config.server.git,PrivateKeyIsValid]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [spring.cloud.config.server.git.,]; arguments []; default message []]; default message [Property 'spring.cloud.config.server.git.privateKey' is not a valid private key]

Just as my error but the key is in correct format. I can't figure out what's wrong, any ideas? I copy the private key with the following command in macosx `pbcopy < ~/.ssh/id_rsa` to the docker-compose file, so it should be the correct file content and also the first line says **-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----**

Furthermore I checked that the private key fingerprint (`ssh-keygen -l -f id_rsa.pub`) is the same as in my git account, which it was.

I also tried different indentations but no luck.